# Why will my local variable not change as the tabs change?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm having trouble getting my local variables to switch between tabs. The locals are set under the h3 tag under each tab that uses the form. From there, the local is passed to the category variable so my form can use it as a partial. Currently, it is only pulling the first local variable, "Associates", no matter what tab is selected.

Is there a way to make sure that the category variable is getting the correct local passed to it based on the tab selected?

Thanks in advance.

```
_form.html.erb

<%= form_for(@best_practice) do |f| %>
<% if @best_practice.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@best_practice.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this best practice from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @best_practice.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field" style="width:90%;">
  <%= f.label :title %><p class="tabbertab-lbreak"></p>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :category, :value => @category %>
  </div>
  <div class="field" style="width:90%;">
  <%= f.label :body %><p class="tabbertab-lbreak"></p>
  <%= f.text_area :body, :cols => 30, :rows => 5 %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit(class: 'btn btn-large btn-primary') %>
  </div>
  <% end %>

 company.html.erb

 <div class="tabbable full-width-tabs">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
            <li class="active take-all-space-you-can"><a href="#tab-one" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
            <li class="take-all-space-you-can"><a href="#tab-two" data-toggle="tab">Associate</a></li>
            <li class="take-all-space-you-can"><a href="#tab-three" data-toggle="tab">Safety</a></li>
            <li class="take-all-space-you-can"><a href="#tab-four" data-toggle="tab">Order Fulfillment</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-one">
              <h3 class="splash-header">Welcome!</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur condimentum a purus vitae lobortis. Donec at nulla in lorem luctus semper. Nam porta dui eget pharetra pretium. Maecenas vitae porta est, sit amet auctor diam. Vestibulum mollis lectus mi, sed ultrices eros scelerisque in. Vivamus ultrices laoreet sem, id venenatis risus facilisis sit amet. Ut a hendrerit nisi, ut laoreet dui.</p><p>Proin laoreet massa sed dictum elementum. Nulla quis suscipit nisi. Etiam aliquam at nibh et feugiat. Pellentesque gravida lorem id erat elementum accumsan. Fusce sit amet enim nec nunc hendrerit molestie. Ut quis orci viverra tortor lobortis fringilla. Aenean in ligula dui. Morbi ornare malesuada augue, sed elementum purus varius ut. Fusce suscipit orci id diam tristique, ut semper lorem cursus. Proin urna massa, pulvinar at sapien vitae, tempor cursus sem. Nunc sit amet nibh sit amet odio luctus ultrices vel congue sem. Maecenas elementum, turpis nec cursus volutpat, diam quam faucibus ipsum, pellentesque tincidunt mi velit eget ligula. Aenean elementum, neque vel accumsan rutrum, risus diam posuere risus, sit amet semper risus magna sed nibh. Pellentesque quis risus at dui bibendum ornare ut vel augue. Aliquam et nunc sit amet dolor vehicula eleifend.</p>                    
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-two">
                <h3 class="splash-header">Post Best Practice</h3>
                   <% @associate = "Associate" %>
                   <%= render 'best_practices/form', local: {category: @associate} %>
                  <h3 class="splash-header">View Best Practice</h3>
                   <ul>
                   <% BestPractice.with_category("Associate").each do |bp| %>
                   <li><%= link_to bp.title, best_practice_path(bp) %></li>
                   <% end %>
                  </ul>     
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-three">
                <h3 class="splash-header">Post Best Practice</h3>
                  <% @safety = "Safety" %>
                  <%= render 'best_practices/form', local: {category: @safety} %>
                  <h3 class="splash-header">View Best Practice</h3>
                   <ul>
                   <% BestPractice.with_category("Safety").each do |bp| %>
                   <li><%= link_to bp.title, best_practice_path(bp) %></li>
                   <% end %>
                  </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-four">
                <h3 class="splash-header">Post Best Practice</h3>
                  <% @order = "Order Fulfillment" %>
                  <%= render 'best_practices/form', local: {category: @order}  %>
                    <h3 class="splash-header">View Best Practice</h3>
                     <ul>
                      <% BestPractice.with_category("Order Fulfillment").each do |bp| %>
                      <li><%= link_to bp.title, best_practice_path(bp) %></li>
                     <% end %>
                     </ul>
            </div>  
        </div> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The _form.html.erb needs to simple use `category` instead of `@category`.

For your company.html.erb, try

```
 <%= render 'best_practices/form', :category => @associate %>
```

This will assign `@associate` to the `:category` variable, and it can be accessed on the other side as simple `category`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `_form` partial, you need to reference `category` as `category`, not `@category`.

Also, `local` should be `locals`, and I think you have to call `render` with the `partial` key to pass in locals, e.g.:

```
render partial: 'best_practices/form', locals: {category: @order}
```